# Download multiple file from blob as Zip folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

My files are in blob storage.So how i can download the multiple files from folder as zip

I am trying this code from some time it is working but not giving me output.Means its not starting the zip download.:
string zipFileName = "MyZipFiles.zip";

```
    using (var zipOutputStream = new 
    ZipOutputStream(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream))
                    {
                    zipOutputStream.SetLevel(0);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFileName);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
                    foreach (var filePath in fileUrl)
                        {
                            var filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath.filename);
                            var filebytes = filePath.filebyte.BlobByteArray;
                            var fileEntry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(filePath.filename))
                            {
                                Size = filebytes.Length
                            };
                        zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(fileEntry);
                        zipOutputStream.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length);
                        }
                    zipOutputStream.Flush();
                    zipOutputStream.Close();                        
                }
```

My file url contains:

```
            foreach (var item in obj)
            {
                em = new FileUrlForbyte();
                em.filename = item.FileName;
                em.url = objBlobHelper.GetFileByFileNameMultiple(item.ContainerName, item.SubFolderName + "/" + item.FileName, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2));
                em.filebyte = objBlobHelper.DownloadFileByFileNameForAdobe(item.ContainerName, item.SubFolderName + "/" + item.FileName);
                fileUrl.Add(em);
            }
```

FOr more clarity:filePath contains:filename,fileurl and file byte:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
    [Route("api/Blob/getMultipleFileFromBlobByURI")]
    [HttpGet]
    public System.Web.Mvc.FileResult getMultipleFileFromBlobByURI(string containerName)        
    {           

        List<BlobStorageModel> obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<BlobStorageModel>>(containerName);
        try
        {               

            BlobHelper objBlobHelper = new BlobHelper(apiPrincipal);
            List<FileUrlForbyte> fileUrl = new List<FileUrlForbyte>();
            FileUrlForbyte em = new FileUrlForbyte();
            
            foreach (var item in obj)
            {
                em = new FileUrlForbyte();
                em.filename = item.FileName;
                em.url = objBlobHelper.GetFileByFileNameMultiple(item.ContainerName, item.SubFolderName + "/" + item.FileName, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2));
                em.filebyte = objBlobHelper.DownloadFileByFileNameForAdobe(item.ContainerName, item.SubFolderName + "/" + item.FileName);
                fileUrl.Add(em);
            }


            // Here we will create zip file & download
            string zipFileName = "MyZipFiles.zip";
            var fileName = string.Format("{0}_ImageFiles.zip", DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "_1");
            var tempOutPutPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Url.Content("/TempImages/")) + fileName;

            try
            { 
                using (var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream))
                    {
                    zipOutputStream.SetLevel(9);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFileName);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
                    foreach (var filePath in fileUrl)
                        {

                      var filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath.filename);
                        var filebytes = filePath.filebyte.BlobByteArray;
                        var fileEntry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(filePath.filename))
                        {
                            Size = filebytes.Length
                        };
                        zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(fileEntry);
                        zipOutputStream.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length);
                    }
                    zipOutputStream.Finish();
                    zipOutputStream.Flush();
                    zipOutputStream.Close();                        
                }
                byte[] finalResult = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempOutPutPath);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(tempOutPutPath))
                    System.IO.File.Delete(tempOutPutPath);

                if (finalResult == null || !finalResult.Any())
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("No Files found with Image"));
               return new System.IO.File(finalResult, "application/zip", fileName);



            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: You are reading the outputStream and saving it to file, right? i can't see that File save command, can you post that?

Comment: I have written this much only.Not sure what to do next now,so that file downloading will start.

Comment: If you need a File to download, you need to return that File from your method. Check this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/download-files-in-zip-formate-in-mvc-net/ . It might help you to read the data from stream and save using File

Comment: I have used the code given in your referred tutorial.Now i am facing issue to return the File which i was facing earlier also
Please check the screenshots which recently updated.

Comment: Can anyone correct the code?

Comment: the error near file should be corrected as System.IO.File

Comment: @Sudheer: Still getting the error.Please check the screenshot.

Comment: @Sudheer:From many days i am stuck at this this issueBut not getting any solution for this zip download. I updated full code which i used.Please check .

Comment: `public FileResult getMultipleFileFromBlobByURI(string containerName) `

this should be your class

` return  File(finalResult, "application/zip", fileName) `

this should be your return type. It is working for me after changing those

Comment: Please check my recent posted screenshot. I am facing this issue.

Comment: I tried System.IO also.

Comment: You shouldn't use 'new' everytime, just use System.IO.File and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sudheer for your inputs in the comments.

> I am trying this code from some time it is working but not giving me output.Means its not starting the zip download.: string zipFileName = “MyZipFiles.zip”;

Referring to the above comment I have tried the below code and was able to execute it successfully.

```
           CloudStorageAccount storage_Account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccount_connectionString);
           CloudBlobClient blob_Client = storage_Account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

           CloudBlobContainer container = blob_Client.GetContainerReference(container_Name);
           CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
           
           Stream file = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Tools\" + filename);    
   
           cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStream(file);

           Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
```

Then, I have created a container in my storage account as shown below.

[image]

We need to upload the zip file into the above folder and run the given code.

[image]

Now I can see that I can access my container and download the zip file located inside the container.

[image]

Comment: This code is to download zip folder.But my question is how i will create zip folder first.My above code is not working.
My files are in a container.For that i have URL and bytes for each file.But that should be download as zip.